# What does -w do in pydoc and can it generate .doc output?

Tags: python, pydoc

What does `-w` do? Will it always generate an html file? Can I generate a `.doc` file instead?

When I execute the command below, it generates an ex.html file.

```
F:\PY>python –m pydoc –w ex
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pydoc.html

Comment: Nice: ask a question, get two answers, disappear.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pydoc.html) <sup>([v2 version](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html))</sup>:

> Specifying a `-w` flag before the argument will cause HTML documentation to be written out to a file in the current directory, instead of displaying text on the console.

There is no option for generating a Microsoft Word `.doc` file.

Answer (score 1):

try `python -m pydoc` in terminal. You can see all that you can do with pydoc.

Well there is no option to provide the file type you want, so the best should be to create a .html file and then convert it into .doc